# Add classes onclick and then remove them with onfocus event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I'm mixing JS and jQuery. I would like to find one unique solution with JS only possibly.

How can I organize the code according to best code practices?

Another thing I need to add is a check at the beginning of the function. If the classes are there nothing should happen, if not there then add them just as below.

```
function changeClass() {
    document.getElementById("message").className += " dropzone-wrap";
    document.getElementById("dragNdrop").className += " dropzone-content";
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("ToggleTxTDrop").addEventListener( 'click' , changeClass );
}

/* lets remove the previous classes when on focus */
$('#message').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('dropzone-wrap');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('dropzone-content');
})
```

Comment: I'll just... drop this here: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: I think that's really helpful however I dont know how to refactor my code above. Any help in refactor it using pure Java Script I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step conversion from your code to the JS-only code of [youmightnotneedjquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com).

```
function changeClass() {
    document.getElementById("message").className += " dropzone-wrap";
    document.getElementById("dragNdrop").className += " dropzone-content";
}
```

Your method here can only ever be used to add "*dropzone-wrap*" and "*dropzone-content*". Consider a different approach, where you provide the `DOM Element` and `CSS Classes` as parameters.

Consider two such methods - one to add the class (from `$.addClass()`), and one to remove it (`$.removeClass()`).

```
// http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#add_class
function addClass(el, className) {
    if (el.classList)
      el.classList.add(className);
    else
      el.className += ' ' + className;
}

// http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#remove_class
function removeClass(el, className) {
    if (el.classList)
      el.classList.remove(className);
    else
      el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
}
```

Note that I'd remove the class before adding it, as that code does not protect against long repeated classname strings.

Anyway, let's continue with your code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("ToggleTxTDrop").addEventListener( 'click' , changeClass );
}
```

Using `onload` works, but it isn't the right way to do it. With jQuery this should be `$(window).on('load', function() { ... });`... with native Javascript, it isn't much different (`.addEventListener`).

For the function code itself, create a handler method that uses the `addClass()` abstraction method to replace your old `changeClass()` functionality:

```
function txtDropClicked(evt) {
    addClass(document.getElementById('message'), 'dropzone-wrap');
    addClass(document.getElementById('dragNdrop'), 'dropzone-content');
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("ToggleTxTDrop").addEventListener( 'click' , txtDropClicked );
});
```

Now we have your classes being added on click; let's update the onfocus handler in the same fashion:

```
/* lets remove the previous classes when on focus */
function removeClassesOnFocus(evt) {
    // evt.target is the element that triggered the event. We bound to #message.
    removeClass(evt.target, 'dropzone-wrap');
    removeClass(evt.target.parentNode, 'dropzone-content');
}

// this bit really should wait for `window.load` too.
document.getElementById('message').addEventListener('focus', removeClassesOnFocus);
```

> If the classes are there nothing should happen

To address that, the `removeClassesOnFocus` function could be reworked to look up the element if it isn't provided.

```
function txtDropClicked(evt) {
    removeClassesOnFocus(false);
    addClass(document.getElementById('message'), 'dropzone-wrap');
    addClass(document.getElementById('dragNdrop'), 'dropzone-content');
}

function removeClassesOnFocus(evt) {
    // evt.target is the element that triggered the event. We bound to #message.
    var message = (evt === false) ? document.getElementById('message') : evt.target;
    removeClass(message, 'dropzone-wrap');
    removeClass(message.parentNode, 'dropzone-content');
}
```

---

**The full converted code:**

```
// http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#add_class
function addClass(el, className) {
    if (el.classList) { el.classList.add(className); }
    else { el.className += ' ' + className; }
}

// http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#remove_class
function removeClass(el, className) {
    if (el.classList) { el.classList.remove(className); }
    else { el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' '); }
}

// When the txtDrop toggle is clicked, add these classes to the message and drag/drop thing.
function txtDropClicked(evt) {
    removeClassesOnFocus(false);
    addClass(document.getElementById('message'), 'dropzone-wrap');
    addClass(document.getElementById('dragNdrop'), 'dropzone-content');
}

// Removes the classes after the message receives focus.
function removeClassesOnFocus(evt) {
    // evt.target is the element that triggered the event. We bound to #message.
    var message = (evt === false) ? document.getElementById('message') : evt.target;
    removeClass(message, 'dropzone-wrap');
    removeClass(message.parentNode, 'dropzone-content');
}

// Attach the click handler to txtDrop toggle when the page loads.
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("ToggleTxTDrop").addEventListener( 'click' , txtDropClicked );
    document.getElementById('message').addEventListener('focus', removeClassesOnFocus);
});
```

It is worth noting that you can use inline functions as handlers, too - and not define `txtDropClicked` or `removeClassesOnFocus`. Either way, the point of each method is to perform a single task, and to do that in the most reusable manner possible.

Comment: Terrific! That's some great learning there. I have this code in place and it works perfectly now. Could you tell me more about the dom element? Would this be: "txtDropClicked" the dom element?

Comment: This code is just a reworking of what you already had, and assumed the same markup. The DOM element IDs are what you had previously defined in `getElementById`. `txtDropClicked()` is an event handler which is being bound to `#ToggleTxTDrop`.

Answer (score 1):

I am puzzled by the lack of parallelism.

- Your `changeClass()` would be more accurately called `addClasses()`.  However, the inverse operation is just an anonymous function for `$('#message').on(…)`.
- `$('#message').on(…)` uses jQuery, but nothing else does.
- `$('#message').on(…)` refers to `$(this).parent()` which presumably refers to the same element as `document.getElementById("dragNdrop")`.

In addition, you have one onClick handler and one onFocus handler. I don't know if you are intentionally listening for two different types of events.

Once you clean up all of these inconsistencies, the code should be a lot easier to understand.